# How do I reload/animate highcharts everytime I click on a button?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts. Everything seems to work fine. I am trying to enhance the loading process. By default when the page loads, chart shows data for "ZX". When I click on "XZ", or "X" button, the chart doesn't animate. It displays instantly. Is there a way I can animate the chart everytime user clicks on any of the buttons? Here is link to my code -

https://live.datatables.net/nikusucu/5/edit

```js
function initializeChart(chartId, tableId, chartTitle) {
    // Create DataTable
    const table = new DataTable(tableId, {
        searching: false,
        info: false,
        paging: false,
        sort: false
    });

    // Create chart
    const chart = Highcharts.chart(chartId, {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            styledMode: false
          
        },
        title: {
            text: chartTitle
        },
       colors: ['#003489', '#ED7D31', '#A5A5A5', '#FFC000', '#5B9BD5', '#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '</b> {point.y:.1f}%'
        },
        series: [
            {
                data: chartData(table)
            }
             
        ],
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                series: {
            animation: {
                duration: 2000
            }
        },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                },
                showInLegend: true  // Show legends
            }
        }
    });

    // On each draw, update the data in the chart
    table.on('draw', function () {
        chart.series[0].setData(chartData(table));
    });

    function chartData(table) {
        var data = [];
        table.rows().every(function () {
            var row = this.data();
            data.push({
                name: row[0],  // Assuming the first column is the name
                y: parseFloat(row[1])  // Assuming the second column is the numeric value
            });
        });

        return data;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Check if Highcharts is defined before calling the function
    if (typeof Highcharts !== 'undefined') {
        initializeChart('demo-output', '#example', 'test1');
        initializeChart('demo-output2', '#example1', 'test 2');

        var allSeriesData = [];
        var categories = [];
        $('#example2').data('scrollX-custom', true);

        var table = $("#example2").DataTable({
            searching: false,
            lengthChange: false,
            ordering: false,
            info: false,
            paging: false,
            initComplete: function (settings, json) {
                let api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);

                // get the x-axis caregories from the table headings:
                var headers = api.columns().header().toArray();
                headers.forEach(function (heading, index) {
                    if (index > 0 && index < headers.length - 1) {
                        categories.push($(heading).html());
                    }
                });

                // get the seris data as an array of numbers from the table row data:
                let rows = api.rows().data().toArray();
                rows.forEach(function (row) {
                    group = {
                        name: '',
                        data: []
                    };
                    row.forEach(function (cell, idx) {
                        if (idx == 0) {
                            group.name = cell;
                        } else if (idx < row.length - 1) {
                            group.data.push(parseFloat(cell.replace(/,/g, '')));
                        }
                    });
                    allSeriesData.push(group);
                });
            }
        });

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            lang: {
                thousandsSep: ','
            }
        });

        var myChart = Highcharts.chart("chart-A", {
            chart: {
                type: "column",
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderWidth: 1,
                marginTop: 50
            },
            legend: {
                symbolRadius: 0,
                itemStyle: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontSize: '16px'
                }
            },
            
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
         
            title: {
                text: "Test3"
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories,
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: '600',
                        fontSize: '16px',
                        color: '#000000'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: false,
                tickInterval: 10,
                max: 70,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                    },
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: '600',
                        fontSize: '16px',
                        color: '#000000'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: allSeriesData
        });

        // Button click event listeners
        $('.usa-button').on('click', function () {
    var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');

    // Toggle chart visibility based on button click
    if (buttonId === 'button-2') {
        $('#chart1').hide();
        $('#chart2').show();
        $('#chart3').hide();
    } else if (buttonId === 'button-3') {
        $('#chart1').hide();
        $('#chart2').hide();
        $('#chart3').show();
    } else {
        // Default case, show chart1
        $('#chart1').show();
        $('#chart2').hide();
        $('#chart3').hide();
    }

    // Highlight the active button
    $('.usa-button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

// Set default highlight on button-2023
$('#button-1').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/dataTables.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/dataTables.js"></script>

 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>


<div class="ar-controls grid-row tablet:flex-justify-start">
<div class="tablet:grid-col-auto margin-bottom-205"><button id="button-1" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">zx</button>
<button id="button-2" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">xz</button>
<button id="button-3" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">x</button>
  </div>
<div id="chart1">
<div id="demo-output" class="chart-display" style=" margin-bottom: 2em; height: 650px; border: solid 1px lightgray;"></div>

<table id="example" class="display" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">test 1</th>
<th scope="col">Percent</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tr>
<td scope="row">1</td>
<td>3.2%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">2</td>
<td>1.1%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">3</td>
<td>1.6%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">4</td>
<td>1.9%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">5</td>
<td>2.5%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">6</td>
<td>4.4%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">7</td>
<td>18.6%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">8</td>
<td>1.1%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">9</td>
<td>1.4%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">10</td>
<td>1.9%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">11</td>
<td>2.2%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">12</td>
<td>3.4%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">13</td>
<td>5.0%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">14</td>
<td>51.9%</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="chart2" style=" display: none;">
<div id="demo-output2" class="chart-display2" style=" margin-bottom: 2em; height: 600px; border: solid 1px lightgray;"></div>

<table id="example1" class="display" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">1</th>
<th scope="col">Percent</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tr>
<td scope="row">2</td>
<td>18.6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">3</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">4</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">5</td>
<td>5.0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">6</td>
<td>2.2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">7</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">8</td>
<td>2.5</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">9</td>
<td>3.4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">10</td>
<td>4.4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">11</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">12</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">13</td>
<td>12.2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="chart3" style=" display: none;"><!--<div style=" text-align: center;"><img src="/images/complaint-data-chart-1.svg" alt="Cases Received From Consumers" title="Cases Received From Consumers" style=" width: 700px;" /></div> -->
<div id="chart-A" style=" width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

<table class="row-border stripe dt-right dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" id="example2" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 12%;">Year</th>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 22%;">1</th>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 22%;">2</th>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 22%;">3</th>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 22%;">4</th>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 22%;">5</th>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 22%;">6</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: center;">2019</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">42.5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">30.1%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">12.5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">6%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">11.3%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">10%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: center;">2020</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">50.01%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">26.5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">15%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">12%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">11%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">10%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: center;">2021</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">29.5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">35%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">66%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">7%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">6%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">56%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: center;">2022</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">40.1%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">76%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">7%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">8%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">86%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">54%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: center;">2023</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">38.9%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">55%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">45%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">55%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">55%</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has already been answered on the [highcharts forum](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/)

**[Q: Animation on show/hide of a chart](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=42298)**

*A: The simplest way is to render the chart again on click: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pMzLNj?editors=0010*

*Solution*

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', chartOptions)
let hidden = false

function showHide(){
   if (!hidden) {
     chart.destroy()
   } else {
     chart = Highcharts.chart('container', chartOptions)
   }
  hidden = !hidden;
}
```

To apply this solution to your code you need to save the Chart in a variable when you initialize it. For example you could return it within your `initializeChart` function. Then call `.destroy` on the reference and set a new one on the variable. There are multiple ways of implementing this solution. Your approach wasn't clean and easy for me to read. I recommend sticking to what the linked solution does:

- separate function for the chartOptions
- using only one container for your chart

Documentation for [Highchart.Chart#destroy](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#destroy)

For the sake of already diving to deep into this and to avoid further discussion - this code should work within your local environment. Please keep in mind that online live editors might not work as explained in [this](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=35275) forum post.

```js
function initializeChart(chartId, table, chartTitle) {
    function chartData(table) {
        var data = [];
        table.rows().every(function() {
            var row = this.data();
            data.push({
                name: row[0],
                y: parseFloat(row[1])
            });
        });

        return data;
    }

    return Highcharts.chart(chartId, {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            styledMode: false
        },
        title: {
            text: chartTitle
        },
        colors: ['#003489', '#ED7D31', '#A5A5A5', '#FFC000', '#5B9BD5', '#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '</b> {point.y:.1f}%'
        },
        series: [{
            data: chartData(table)
        }],
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        accessibility: {
          enabled: false
        }
    });
}

const createDataTable = (id) => new DataTable(id, {
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    paging: false,
    sort: false
});
const table1 = createDataTable('#example')
const table2 = createDataTable('#example1')
const table3 = createDataTable('#example2')

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let currentChart
    if (typeof Highcharts !== 'undefined') {
        currentChart = initializeChart('demo-output', table1, 'test1');


        $('.usa-button').on('click', function() {
            var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');

            if (currentChart) {
                currentChart.destroy();
            }

            if (buttonId === 'button-2') {
                currentChart = initializeChart('demo-output', table2, 'test 2');
            } else if (buttonId === 'button-3') {
                currentChart = initializeChart('demo-output', table3, 'test 3');
            } else {
                currentChart = initializeChart('demo-output', table1, 'test 1');
            }

            $('.usa-button').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });

        $('#button-1').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/dataTables.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/dataTables.js"></script>

 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>


<div class="ar-controls grid-row tablet:flex-justify-start">
<div class="tablet:grid-col-auto margin-bottom-205"><button id="button-1" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">zx</button>
<button id="button-2" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">xz</button>
<button id="button-3" class="usa-button usa-button--outline">x</button>
  </div>
<div id="chart1">
<div id="demo-output" class="chart-display" style=" margin-bottom: 2em; height: 650px; border: solid 1px lightgray;"></div>

<table id="example" class="display" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">test 1</th>
<th scope="col">Percent</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tr>
<td scope="row">1</td>
<td>3.2%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">2</td>
<td>1.1%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">3</td>
<td>1.6%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">4</td>
<td>1.9%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">5</td>
<td>2.5%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">6</td>
<td>4.4%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">7</td>
<td>18.6%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">8</td>
<td>1.1%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">9</td>
<td>1.4%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">10</td>
<td>1.9%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">11</td>
<td>2.2%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">12</td>
<td>3.4%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">13</td>
<td>5.0%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">14</td>
<td>51.9%</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="chart2" style=" display: none;">
<div id="demo-output2" class="chart-display2" style=" margin-bottom: 2em; height: 600px; border: solid 1px lightgray;"></div>

<table id="example1" class="display" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">1</th>
<th scope="col">Percent</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tr>
<td scope="row">2</td>
<td>18.6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">3</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">4</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">5</td>
<td>5.0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">6</td>
<td>2.2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">7</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">8</td>
<td>2.5</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">9</td>
<td>3.4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">10</td>
<td>4.4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">11</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">12</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">13</td>
<td>12.2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="chart3" style=" display: none;"><!--<div style=" text-align: center;"><img src="/images/complaint-data-chart-1.svg" alt="Cases Received From Consumers" title="Cases Received From Consumers" style=" width: 700px;" /></div> -->
<div id="chart-A" style=" width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

<table class="row-border stripe dt-right dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" id="example2" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 12%;">Year</th>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 22%;">1</th>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 22%;">2</th>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 22%;">3</th>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 22%;">4</th>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 22%;">5</th>
<th scope="col" style=" text-align: center; width: 22%;">6</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: center;">2019</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">42.5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">30.1%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">12.5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">6%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">11.3%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">10%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: center;">2020</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">50.01%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">26.5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">15%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">12%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">11%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">10%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: center;">2021</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">29.5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">35%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">66%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">7%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">6%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">56%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: center;">2022</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">40.1%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">76%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">7%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">8%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">86%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">54%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: center;">2023</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">38.9%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">55%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">45%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">55%</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">55%</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work. now my other charts also do not load. what am I missing?
https://live.datatables.net/nikusucu/15/edit

Comment: @newuser I added a running code sample (wich does not work in your `live.datatables.net` environment). I wont go any further in this topic as in my opinion there is way more provided than needed to implement a running solution. If you have other issues feel free to create a new question.

Comment: @newuser you never returned the chart from your init function. Also you forgot to set the initial Chart in your variable. The above solution applied the working example from the forum and the official documentation. Please try it in a local environment and if you get new errors (on the console) create a new question. The above should work.

Comment: I am still struggling with this. I am not sure why I need to submit the question again. Is there someone else who could help me?

Comment: I added the full HTML, CSS and JavaScript to my answer. You can live check it here in the Editor. It works. The time invested into this answer is fully streched and I wont support any more as I feel I have to give a tutorial instead of answering a specific question. I still would be happy if this now works for you and you can give me an upvote (if the answer fits for you).

Comment: As small bonus: I fixed you a further bug in your code. You create always new DataTables wich is by design not intended and will causes errors in the future.